# bad screen resolution after graphical driver issues

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, display-resolution, nouveau

During my internship, I have some serious issues with the computer I have to work on. 
The main issue: I needed to use NVIDIA drivers to use some specific programs. So, I tried to install these.

Unfortunately, everything went wrong from there. I followed the steps from several web pages to install these drivers, but nonetheless I had some serious display issues.

The main problem right now is that I only have one screen resolution available in my `Displays` options (that being `640x480`, which is *waaaay* to low).

I wanted to change this resolution using several methods, ranging from using `xrandr --addmode` to editing the `xorg.conf` file

As my deadline is creeping closer, and I tried really a lot of different methods, I kindly ask for help, as I am all out of options.

I posted the output of my `xorg.conf` file below.

Can someone tell me how to get a normal resolution back? The `xrandr` method works to some extent: **I can add a new resolution option** in my displays field, **but I cannot select and press apply**.

If I look at the `additional drivers` field, I see that the system is using `X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`

I run on Ubuntu 14.04

If you need additional information, please ask, I will be only the whole time!

Thanks

Output of `xorg.conf` file:

---

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 304.137  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-01)  Thu Sep 14 15:01:30 PDT 2017

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Have a look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. I bet something went wrong with the graphics driver and now it falls back to vesa or something.

Comment: @mbeyss indeed, in this file, I see this: `VESA(0): *Built-in mode "640x480"` , which is indeed my current resolution
An idea how I fix this?

Comment: Check `Xorg.0.log` for lines with `EE` and `WW` they might tell you what went wrong (and why you are falling back to to vesa). Also check if the  `nvidia` module is loaded (by `lsmod | grep nvidia`). If not try to load it (`modprobe nvidia`). Any errors there? Is there some information in the syslog? (`dmesg`)